# How to find all the word present in a values of large json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have a huge json file, which contains number of key, value pair

For example:

```
[

{"header": "hi", "description": " It contain some value ","file_name": "sile.xls", "file_path": "/home", "id": "12"}, 

{"header": "hello", "description": "it has value", "file_name": "s.docs", "file_path": "/home",  "id": "34"}

]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2iv5.png)

I want output wrt key[description] :

---> it -2 , contain-1, some-1, value-2, has-1

Please help please

Comment: show what you have done your code also can you explain a bit more clearly the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
inp = [{'file_path': '/home', 'header': 'hi', 'id': '12', 'description': ' It contain some value ', 'file_name': 'sile.xls'}, {'file_path': '/home', 'header': 'hello', 'id': '34', 'description': 'it has value', 'file_name': 's.docs'}]
```

Code

```
res={}
for i in inp:
   k = i['description'].split()
   for n in k:
      if not n in res:
            res[n]=1
      else:
            res[n] +=1
print(res)
```

Output

```
{'some': 1, 'it': 1, 'value': 2, 'It': 1, 'contain': 1, 'has': 1}
```